# Is it possible to create a div that blurs anything that appears below it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like a div that creates a Gaussian blur type effect on anything that appears under it. Anyone come across anything like that? Pixastic (http://www.pixastic.com) can blur images dynamically, but I think it needs pixel data to do its transformation. I just want a region that is dynamically blurry. Thanks!

Comment: It is impossible unless you can reproduce all rendering process of underlying content.

Comment: You can use the practice in this link [which talks about CSS3 and JQuery to blur elements](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/14/item-blur-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/)

Comment: You can using SVG filters. Full support across browsers is a while away yet, but if you have a recent version of FireFox you can see an example of an SVG overlay being used to add effects to a video here: http://paulirish.com/work/videooo.xhtml This page talks a little more about it and has some examples with images: http://www.dhmedia.com.au/blog/photography-effects-svg-filters

Comment: it`s your: http://blogfreakz.com/web-design/item-blur-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/ or: http://www.jqueryrain.com/2011/12/item-blur-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: It seems that you are correct kirilloid, it's either on the horizon with the canvas element or just text/div content via javascript currently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Killroid left the correct answer in comment form:

It is impossible unless you can reproduce all rendering process of underlying content. – kirilloid